# Ubuntu 19.04, 18.04 Does not mount NTFS partition,/dev/sdax Unknown error, Dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, 19.04, ntfs

I have a problem with ubuntu 19.04.

(Images are attached as links)

It seems that ubuntu wont mount a ntfs partition,i've seen some similar problems in this forum, but those issues are caused by fast startup(windows) that doesn't allow the partition to be mounted because its bein used.

but this is not the case,i have dualboot alongside windows,well had,because now it does not boot windows
[eError when i try to mount it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eib3.png)

I already tried the comand line:

*sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1*

And what i get is this:

```
jonathan@jonathan-Latitude-E6430:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1
[sudo] password for jonathan: 
Mounting volume... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x18ab4143  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 32776  usa_count: 11052: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x7f272828808e9293) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x0).
Failed to open $Secure: No such file or directory
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x18ab4143  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 32776  usa_count: 11052: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x7f272828808e9293) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x0).
Failed to open $Secure: No such file or directory
Remount failed: No such file or directory
```

The same thing happens when i run this comand:

*sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1*

```
jonathan@jonathan-Latitude-E6430:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
Failed to determine whether /dev/sdb1 is mounted: No such file or directory
Mounting volume... Failed to access '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Failed to access '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: No such file or directory
Failed to access '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

Ill provide you with more details,i launch gparted aplication
It displays this:
[My partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwXPO.png)

[Propieties of the partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF2hY.png)

I hope you can help me, let me know if you know how to fix this.

Comment: NTFS is a foreign file system for GNU/Linux (Ubuntu), so I'd recommend doing a `fsck` (or `chkdsk`) using your native OS - ie. windows.  Boot windows media, or `chkdsk` the disk using another windows box.